# py2exe: code wont modify script once converted

Tags: python, dictionary, py2exe

As a small project I created a small chatroom. The code follows, may I point out that I am new to programming so the structure may not be efficient:

```
import re, time
user_name = 0
password = 0
chatroom = 0

from users import users
def startup():
      global user_name, password, chatroom
      print "\n" * 100
      user_name = raw_input("Your username: ").upper()
      if users.has_key(str(user_name).lower()) == True:
            password = str(raw_input("Password: "))
            while str(users[user_name.lower()]) != str(password):
                  print "Incorrect password."
                  time.sleep(2)
                  startup()
            else:
                  chatroom = raw_input("Room name: ").lower()
                  chat()
      else:
            print "Invalid username."
            time.sleep(2)
            startup()

def showchat():
      global user_name
      file = open(str(chatroom) + ".txt","r+")
      messages = str(file.read()[-700:])
      file.close
      messages = messages.rstrip('\n')
      print "\n" * 40
      print messages
      print "------ type 'r' to refresh the screen ------"

def writechat():
      global user_name, chatroom
      n = raw_input("________________________________________________________" + "\n" + user_name + ": ")      
      if user_name.lower() == 'admin':
            if n == "clear":
                  file = open(str(chatroom) + ".txt","w")
                  file.write("")
                  file.close
            elif n == "addnewuser":
                  x = "'" + raw_input("new username: ") + "'"
                  y = "'" + raw_input("new password: ") + "'"
                  file = open("users.py","r").read()
                  file = file.replace("'username' : 'password',", x + " : " + y + "," + "'username' : 'password',")
                  open("users.py","w").write(file)
            elif n == "r":
                  chat()
            elif n == "logout":
                  startup()
            else:
                  file = open(str(chatroom) + ".txt","a")
                  file.write(user_name + ": " + str(n) + "\n")
                  file.close()
      else:
            if n == "r":
                  chat()
            elif n == "changepassword":
                  file = open("users.py","r")
                  file.read()
                  oldpass = raw_input("New password: ")
                  users[user_name.lower()] = oldpass
                  print users
                  file.close()
                  file = open("users.py","w")
                  file.write("users = " + str(users))         #here
                  file.close()
            elif n == "logout":
                  startup()
            else:
                  file = open(str(chatroom) + ".txt","a")
                  file.write(user_name + ": " + str(n) + "\n")
                  file.close()

def chat():
      showchat()
      writechat()
      chat()


startup()
```

This code works perfectly fine in python as long as a chatroom.txt file exists as well as users.py.
The problem occurs once I convert it to .exe, it works fine except that the users.py file does not get written permanently (it does temporarily) when it should, the relevant coding is marked #here.

my setup code is as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe' : {
'packages': ['users'],
"bundle_files" : 2,
}},
    console = [{'script': "chatroom.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

users.py is simply just a dictionary of (user:password):

```
users = {
'admin' : '2588619',
'john' : '1234',
'username' : 'password',
}
```

so how do I convert it to .exe and make it so users.py gets written permanently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package created by py2exe is simply an auto-extracting archive that contains a python interpreter and your program. Everytime the .exe is run everything inside gets extracted in a temporary directory and the program is run by the extracted interpreter.
This means that what you're trying to achieve is simply not possible if you put `users.py` together with the source code.

You should create a `users.py` file in some user directory, for example:

```
users = open(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), '_MyProgram', 'users.py'))
```

Obviously you should also make sure that this directory exists, and eventually create it.

This can be done automatically by py2exe passing the [`data_files`](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/data_files) parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it by changing the users file to text (:

Answer (score 0):

I think it's in the name of users.py py2exe thinks it is a file that it needs to handle. Rename it to users.db or something else. See if that works.